# Keep one line out of many that starts from one point

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I am working on a project with OpenCV and python but stuck on this small problem.

I have end-points' coordinates on many lines stored in a list. Sometimes a case is appearing that from a single point, more than one line is detected. From among these lines, I want to keep the line of shortest length and eliminate all the other lines thus my image will contain no point from where more than one line is drawn.

My variable which stores the information(coordinates of both the end-points) of all the lines initially detected is as follows:

```
var = [[Line1_EndPoint1, Line1_EndPoint2],
       [Line2_EndPoint1, Line2_EndPoint2],
       [Line3_EndPoint1, Line3_EndPoint2],
       [Line4_EndPoint1, Line4_EndPoint2],
       [Line5_EndPoint1, Line5_EndPoint2]]
```

where, LineX_EndPointY(line number "X", endpoint "Y" of that line) is of type [x, y] where x and y are the coordinates of that point in the image.

Can someone suggest me how to solve this problem.

**You can modify the way data of the lines are stored. If you modify, please explain your data structure and how it is created**

Example of such data:

```
[[[551, 752], [541, 730]], 
 [[548, 738], [723, 548]],
 [[285, 682], [226, 676]],
 [[416, 679], [345, 678]],
 [[345, 678], [388, 674]],
 [[249, 679], [226, 676]],
 [[270, 678], [388, 674]],
 [[472, 650], [751, 473]],
 [[751, 473], [716, 561]],
 [[731, 529], [751, 473]]]
```

Python code would be appreciable.

Comment: I'm confused with the question - your title states that you want to only have one line starting / emitting from any point yet the contents of the question alludes to ending points, not starting points.  Do you mean that you should only have one line with the shortest length that have unique start points and end points, just start points or just end points?

Comment: It doesn't matter from where the lines are starting or ending. The thing is that any 2 lines or more lines in the final output should not have any common endpoint. "Starting" and "Ending" words are just for naming the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A *Numpy* solution

The same result as in my first answer can be achieved based solely
on *Numpy*.

First define of 2 functions:

1. Compute square of the length of a line:

   ```
    def sqLgth(line):
        p1, p2 = line
        return (p1[0] - p2[0]) ** 2 + (p1[1] - p2[1]) ** 2
   ```
2. Convert a vector (*1D* array) to a column array (a *2D* array
   with a single column:

   ```
    def toColumn(tbl):
        return tbl.reshape(-1, 1)
   ```

Both will be used later.

Then proceed as follows:

1. Get the number of lines:

   ```
    lineNo = var.shape[0]
   ```
2. Generate line indices (the content of *lineInd* column in *points* array
   (will be created later)):

   ```
    id = np.repeat(np.arange(lineNo), 2)
   ```
3. Generate "origin indicators" (1 - start, 2 - end), to ease analysis
   of any intermediate printouts:

   ```
    origin = np.tile(np.array([1, 2]), lineNo)
   ```
4. Compute line lengths (the content of *lgth* column in *points*):

   ```
    lgth = np.repeat([ sqLgth(line) for line in var ], 2)
   ```
5. Create a list of points with some additional data (consecutive
   columns contain *origin*, *lineInd*, *x*, *y* and *lgth*):

   ```
    points = np.hstack([toColumn(origin), toColumn(id),
        var.reshape(-1, 2), toColumn(lgth)])
   ```
6. Compute the "criterion array" to sort:

   ```
    r = np.core.records.fromarrays(points[:, 2:].transpose(),
        names='x, y, lgth')
   ```
7. Sort *points* (by *x*, *y* and *lgth*):

   ```
    points = points[r.argsort()]
   ```
8. Compute "inverse unique indices" to points:

   ```
    _, inv = np.unique(points[:,2:4], axis=0, return_inverse=True)
   ```
9. Shift *inv* by 1 position:

   ```
    rInv = np.roll(inv,1)
   ```

   Will be used in the next step, to get the previous element.
10. Generate a list of line indices to drop:

    ```
    toDrop = points[[ i for i in range(2 * lineNo)
        if inv[i] == rInv[i] ], 1]
    ```

    Row indices (in *points* array) are indices of repeated points (elements
    in *inv* equal to the previous element).

    Column index (*1*) - specifies *lineInd* column.

    The whole result (*toDrop*) is a list of indices of "owning" lines
    (containing the repeated points).
11. Generate the result: *var* stripped from lines selected in the
    previous step:

    ```
    var2 = np.delete(var, toDrop, axis=0)
    ```

To print the reduced list of lines, you can run:

```
for line in var2:
    print(f'{line[0]}, {line[1]}')
```

The result is:

```
[551 752], [541 730]
[548 738], [723 548]
[345 678], [388 674]
[249 679], [226 676]
[731 529], [751 473]
```

To fully comprehend how this code works:

- execute each step separately,
- print the result,
- compare it with printouts from previous steps.

Sometimes it is instructive to print separately even some expressions
(parts of instructions), e.g. `var.reshape(-1, 2)` - converting your
*var* (of shape *(10, 2, 2)*) into a *2D* array of points (each row is
a point).

The whole result is of course just the same as in my first answer,
but as you wrote you had little experience in *Pandas*, now you can
compare both methods and see the cases where *Pandas* allows to do
something easier and more intuitive.

Good examples are e.g. sort by some columns or finding duplicated rows.
In *Pandas* it is a matter of a single instruction, with suitable
parameters, whereas in *Numpy* you have to use more instructions
and know various details and tricks how to do just the same.

Answer (score 1):

I decided that it is easier to write a solution based on *Pandas*.
The reasons are that:

- I can use column names (the code is better readable),
- *Pandas* API is more powerful, although it works slower than "pure" *Numpy*.

Proceed as follows:

1. Convert *var* to a DataFrame:

   ```
    lines = pd.DataFrame(var.reshape(10,4), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        (['P1', 'P2'], ['x','y'])))
   ```

   The initial part of *lines* is:

   ```
        P1        P2     
         x    y    x    y
    0  551  752  541  730
    1  548  738  723  548
    2  285  682  226  676
    3  416  679  345  678
   ```
2. Compute the square of the length of each line:

   ```
    lines[('', 'lgth')] = (lines[('P1', 'x')] - lines[('P2', 'x')]) ** 2\
        + (lines[('P1', 'y')] - lines[('P2', 'y')]) ** 2
    lines.columns = lines.columns.droplevel()
   ```

   I deliberately "stopped" at **squares** of length, because it is
   enough to compare lenghs (computing the root will not change the
   result of comparison).

   Note also that the first level of the MultiIndex on columns was needed
   only to easier express the columns of interest. Further on they will
   not be needed, so I dropped it.

   This time I put the full content of *lines*:

   ```
         x    y    x    y    lgth
    0  551  752  541  730     584
    1  548  738  723  548   66725
    2  285  682  226  676    3517
    3  416  679  345  678    5042
    4  345  678  388  674    1865
    5  249  679  226  676     538
    6  270  678  388  674   13940
    7  472  650  751  473  109170
    8  751  473  716  561    8969
    9  731  529  751  473    3536
   ```
3. The next step is to compute *points* DataFrame, where all points (start and
   end of each line) are in the same columns, along with the (square) length of
   the corresponding line:

   ```
    points = pd.concat([lines.iloc[:,[0, 1, 4]],
        lines.iloc[:,[2, 3, 4]]], keys=['P1', 'P2'])\
        .sort_values(['x', 'y', 'lgth']).reset_index(level=1)
   ```

   Now I used *iloc* to specify columns (the first time for starting points
   and second for ending points).
   To easier read this DataFrame, I passed *keys*, to include "origin
   indicators" and then I sorted rows.

   The content is:

   ```
        level_1    x    y    lgth
    P2        5  226  676     538
    P2        2  226  676    3517
    P1        5  249  679     538
    P1        6  270  678   13940
    P1        2  285  682    3517
    P1        4  345  678    1865
    P2        3  345  678    5042
    P2        4  388  674    1865
    P2        6  388  674   13940
    P1        3  416  679    5042
    P1        7  472  650  109170
    P2        0  541  730     584
    P1        1  548  738   66725
    P1        0  551  752     584
    P2        8  716  561    8969
    P2        1  723  548   66725
    P1        9  731  529    3536
    P2        9  751  473    3536
    P1        8  751  473    8969
    P2        7  751  473  109170
   ```

   Note e.g. that point *226, 676* occurs twice. The first time it occurred
   in line *5* and the second in line *2* (indices in *var* and *lines*).
4. To find indices of rows to drop, run:

   ```
    toDrop = points[points.duplicated(subset=['x', 'y'])]\
        .level_1.reset_index(drop=True);
   ```

   To easier comprehend how this code works, run it step by step and
   inspect results of each step.

   The result is:

   ```
    0    2
    1    3
    2    6
    3    8
    4    7
    Name: level_1, dtype: int64
   ```

   Note that the left column above is the index only (it dosn't matter).
   The real information is in the right column (values).
5. To show lines that should be left, run:

   ```
    result = lines.drop(toDrop)
   ```

   getting:

   ```
         x    y    x    y   lgth
    0  551  752  541  730    584
    1  548  738  723  548  66725
    4  345  678  388  674   1865
    5  249  679  226  676    538
    9  731  529  751  473   3536
   ```

   The above result doesn't contain e.g.:

   - line *2*, as point *226, 676* occurred in line *5*,
   - line *3*, as point *345, 678* occurred in line *4*,

   Just these lines (*2* and *3*) have been dropped because they are
   longer than both second mentioned lines (see earlier partial results).

Maybe this is enough, or if you need to drop the "duplicated" lines from
*var* (the original *Numpy* array), and save the result in another
variable, run:

```
var2 = np.delete(var, toDrop, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. It's a little tricky to understand in one go for me as I have no experience with pandas. Will try to implement this and then mark the question as answered.